# NewMeRequest in the Facebook Android API in C#

Tags: c#, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin

I've been trying to do a Request.NewMeRequest with the Facebook API for Android in Xamarin Studio through the following code:

```
Request.NewMeRequest (currentSession, new Request.IGraphUserCallback() {
    override void OnCompleted(IGraphUser user, Response Response){
        Console.WriteLine(user.FirstName);
    }
}).ExecuteAsync ();
```

But Xamarin Studio gives some errors, so I think i am not doing this the right way in C#. Does someone have some sample code of how to do this or some exaplanation of why this isn't working?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Thanks @Guilherme for the help, it doesn't return any errors now, but i've run into the following problem:

I've changed the code to your answer like this:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, ILocationListener, Request.IGraphUserCallback
{

    ...

    Session currentSession = Session.ActiveSession;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        ...

        Console.WriteLine ("current session: " + currentSession.AccessToken);
        Request.NewMeRequest (currentSession, this).ExecuteAsync();
    }

    public void OnCompleted (IGraphUser user, Response response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (user.Username);
    }

    ...

}
```

But now it doesn't retun the username of the current logged in user. The session is not the problem because it is correct.

Comment: Witch library are you using? For sure this will not work on c#, because it does not support Anonymous class.

Comment: The callback does get called ?

Comment: Never mind, it works now. `user.Username` was null but the user object has the rest of the data so I think Facebook doesn't return the username for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure this will not work on c#, because it does not support Anonymous class

Make your class implement the IGraphUserCallback and pass it as a parameter and then:

```
Request.NewMeRequest (currentSession, this).ExecuteAsync ();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you help me with my new problem I added to the initial question?